# Convert poisson regression results table to wide

Tags: gtsummary, broom

I've read a small function to convert the results to wide: https://gist.github.com/ddsjoberg/a55afa74ac58e1f895862fcabab62406, and wondering if it can be done for poison regression? I'd appreciate using this example below

```
p <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/poisson_sim.csv")
p <- within(p, {
  prog <- factor(prog, levels=1:3, labels=c("General", "Academic", 
                                            "Vocational"))
      id <- factor(id)
    })

glm(num_awards ~ prog+math, family="poisson", data=p) %>%
tbl_regression(exponentiate = TRUE,include=prog) %>%
   add_significance_stars(
     pattern = "{estimate} ({conf.low},{conf.high}){stars}",
     hide_ci = TRUE,
     hide_p = TRUE,
     hide_se = TRUE)
```

Want to convert the table from [image]

to a wide table like this: [image].

But I want the model to be a poisson regression

Comment: can you add an example of what you'd like the results to look like? the code your referencing is for multinomial models with multiple outcomes.

Comment: Dear @DanielD.Sjoberg, I've edited my question with an example. Looking forward to your assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is not a table that can easily be created with the gtsummary package. I think it would be easier to construct using the output from the broom::tidy() function

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg, Thanks for the reply. Would you happen to know how to do that using the broom::tidy() function?